# Namespace module class methods undefined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, module

I'm trying to use modules for namespacing reasons. I have this file located in my Rails app at `/lib/reports/stripe.rb`.

```ruby
module Reports
  module Stripe
    def self.foo
      puts 'i am foo'
    end
  end
end
```

In my console, I'd expect to be able to call foo by `Reports::Stripe.foo` or `Reports::Stripe::foo`, but I get the error

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `foo' for Reports::Stripe:Module
```

What am I doing wrong? Also feel free to let me know if there's a better way to organize the location and namespacing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file was actually located in `/lib/reports/stripe/stripe.rb`. It was a mistake I made much earlier, but forgot to fix. Moving the file to `/lib/reports/stripe.rb` resolved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

All method calls in ruby use the `.` syntax. Even "module" methods.

```
> Reports::Stripe.foo
i am foo
```

You may be receiving the error `NoMethodError: undefined method 'foo' for Reports::Stripe:Module` if you have added the method after you have started the rails console. Try restarting the console or reloading the file with `load 'reports/stripe'`.

Comment: Yea, that was one of the ways I tried calling it (see above). It didn't work on a console restart either. Also, I'm sure that the file is being loaded because I'm not getting any uninitialized errors when running `Reports::Stripe`.

Comment: The error would have been `uninitialized constant Reports` if the file was not loaded. I have no idea why you would get that error - I can't reproduce it either.

Comment: Gah, I figured it out...the file was actually located in `/lib/reports/stripe/stripe.rb`. It was a mistake I made much earlier, but forgot to fix. Moving the file to `/lib/reports/stripe.rb` resolved it.